# Can Zoom's "ask anonymously" be deanonymized?

Tags: zoom-meeting

Is the Zoom Q&A feature, "Ask Anonymously" irreversibly anonymous? Or, can an admin see who asked the question? I'm wondering if this feature can be trusted to ask juicy questions. My assumption is that it's not safe, and whomever pays for the account can see who asked it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [a Zoom employee's response](https://community.zoom.com/t5/Events-and-Webinars/Zoom-Survey-Anonymous-response/m-p/28864/highlight/true#M1520) the admin will not be able to see the info of the user asking the question:

> Once a Webinar has begun and anonymous Q&A has been enabled, it will not be possible to see user names for those asking anonymous questions, either during the Webinar or in subsequent reporting. Zoom Support will also not be able to provide this information for privacy reasons.